# jQuery access to 'this' object with events and triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two classes orchestrated by a main class and I would like to know how to gain access to the correct 'this' object when events are fired among these classes. Here's what I have:

```
// My main class that orchestrates the two worker classes
function MainClass()
{
    this.workerOne = new ChildWorkerOne();
    this.workerOne.bindBehaviors.apply(this.workerOne);

    this.workerTwo = new ChildWorkerTwo();
    this.workerTwo.bindBehaviors.apply(this.workerTwo);

    // a custom event I'm creating and will be triggered by
    // a separate event that occurs in workerTwo
    $(document).bind("customEvent", this.onCustomAction);   
}

MainClass.prototype.onCustomAction = function(event, data)
{
    // I want to call a method that belongs to 'workerOne'. 
    this.workerOne.makeItHappen();

    // However, the 'this' object refers to the 'Document' and 
    // not the 'MainClass' object.
    // How would I invoke 'makeItHappen' here?
};

ChildWorkerOne.prototype.makeItHappen = function()
{
    // Do a bunch of work here
};

ChildWorkerTwo.prototype.bindBehaviors = function()
{
    $(div).click(function(e){
        $.post(url, params, function(data)
        {
            // do a bunch of work with this class and then
            // trigger event to update data with ChildWorkerOne
            $(document).trigger("customEvent", [data]);
        }
    });
};
```

I don't want to merge ChildWorkerOne and ChildWorkerTwo because they are two separate entities that don't belong together and MainClass conceptually should orchestrate the ChildWorkerOne and ChildWorkerTwo. However, I do want to invoke the behavior of one in the other.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to persist the `this` value, you can do it in many ways, jQuery 1.4+ provides you the [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method, e.g.:

```
//...
$(document).bind("customEvent", $.proxy(this.onCustomAction, this));
// or
$(document).bind("customEvent", $.proxy(this, 'onCustomAction'));
//...
```